# How do I extract the Git branch in a jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, jenkins-groovy

I am using the generic webhook trigger to retrieve the names of the branch and the hash from a pull request. 
In the pipeline I would like to merge to a specific branch and hence I would like to extract the name of the branch.

Right now the branch name is stored in a variable and if I echo it is: refs/heads/

I would like to perform a sh 'git merge 
Is there any way I can extract branch_name from refs/heads/?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use environment variable named `BRANCH_NAME` to extract the name of the branch:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('Print branch name') {
            steps {
                echo "Branch is ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Don't be surprised if your PR branch name would be "PR-1234" though.

If you use Github and install [Pipeline Github plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-github-plugin), you have a variable named `pullRequest` which can be used to get information about a pull request and the base branch:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('Print branch name') {
            steps {
                echo "Branch is ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
                script {
                    if (env.CHANGE_ID) {
                        echo "This PR is for the ${pullRequest.headRef} branch"
                        echo "The PR is over the  ${pullRequest.base} branch."
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem. I'm using Bitbucket. I already have the branch name stored in a variable pr_branch. Is there any shell command I can use to remove the refs/head/<branch> to extract the branch name?

Comment: If you need to convert `refs/head/aaa` to `aaa`, you may want to use a regex. `def matcher = long_branch_name =~ "refs/heads/(.*)"` and `if (matcher.matches()) { short_branch_name = matcher.group(1) }`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I tried def 
branchName ="ref/head/devBranch"
def matcher = branchName =~ "refs/heads/(.*)" 
and I get the following error ava.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=refs/heads/(.*) region=0,21 lastmatch=]

Comment: `ref/head` is not the same as `refs/heads`.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured out an elegant solution:

```
def branchName ="ref/head/DevBranch"
```

`def values= branchName.tokenize( '/' )

pipeline{
   agent...
    {
echo "${values[2]}"...